# Android: Change background color of Material TextInputLayout when active

Tags: android, xaml, android-styles

I am trying to change background color of Material TextInputLayout when its active.
When I click the textinputedittext it becomes transparent and I need to set the background color.
I am attaching printscreens.

Many thanks

1. [first view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmVUd.png)
2. [active text input with transparent color -need to keep same blue background not transparent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hk7O8.png)
3. [text input background color is correct when typing text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpOeW.png)

   ```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/etPasswordLayout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:hint="Enter your password"
        app:endIconTint="@null"
        app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
        android:textColorHint="@color/darkBlue"
        app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_password_visibility"
        app:shapeAppearance="@style/Rounded">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassword"
            style="@style/Text.NormalText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corner_toggle"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:minHeight="60dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/darkBlue" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
   ```

Implementation of textchangedlistener:

```
 val layoutPassword = findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.layout_Password)
    val inputPassword = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.input_Password)
    inputPassword.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            layoutPassword.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D0DDFF"))
            inputPassword.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D0DDFF"))
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            layoutPassword.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D0DDFF"))
             inputPassword.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D0DDFF"))
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

use **addTextChangedListener**

```
field1 = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.field1);
field2 = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.field2);

field2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                    int count, int after) {

      // before text change 
      field1.setBackgroundColor() // set your color before active

   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                 int before, int count) {

      // after add text in TextInputEditText
      field1.setBackgroundColor() // set your color after active

   }
  });
```

Comment: sadly not working :( implemented its triggered but not changing background :(